# How can I select rows from a table with numerical values similar to those in another table?

Tags: sas

I have a test and control group of data. Both the test and control group's table has cust_id and NRx(numerical values). Rows in the test group are only 300 while control group have 40,000. I need to select 300-400 rows of control group as another table using SAS such that the NRx in the control group are closely matched within reasonable range with those of test group.  Please help!

Comment: Is the 'reasonable range' is some distinct number e.g. +/- 200?

Comment: The range of test group is 1 to 400. And for control group also it is 1 to 410. So, I need to very closely match control group with test group.

Comment: 'Closely matched', is that a statistical term?;-)  Do the the two groups have the same distibution?  The same range?  Are they Gausian?  Do you want the control and subset matched in distribution, median, mean or.range?

Comment: They have similar distribution and range. I want them matched in distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to do an nth sample of the sorted control list.

In SQL, you can do this in certain databases using the following construct:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by cust_id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where mod(t, 100) = 7
```

This will select every hundredth record, starting with the 7th, for the test group.

Most databases support the row_number() function.  If yours does not, then you can readily do the same thing in a data step in SAS.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Tried this in proc sql.. But its not working. I am new to SAS. Can you explain me in SAS code?

Comment: I don't think proc sql supports the row_number() functionality.  This is easy to do in data step code.  There may also be some sort of "proc sample" available.  I generally use SAS through Enterprise Miner, which has an nth-sample capability.  I'm not sure how it is implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the the 300 nearest the mean of the  test group.  Or,  bin the control group proportional to the test group and pull samples out of the bins in proportion to the distribution in the test group.

Answer (score 0):

First determine your selection criteria (your comment about "reasonable range"); suppose you want to include records from CONTROL that are within plus or minus one std deviation of the mean from SAMPLE.  Try this (a simple random sample without replacement, see [this SAS note](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/722.html)):

```
proc sql noprint;
  /* Find mean and std dev of TEST group into two macro variables */
  select mean(nrx)
      ,  std(nrx) 
  into :mean_nrx, :std_nrx
  from TEST;

  /* Create TARGET based on +/- 1 std deviation  */
  create table TARGET as
  select *
  from   CONTROL
  where  NRx between (&mean_nrx - &std_nrx) and (&mean_nrx + &std_nrx);
quit;

/* Create sample of size K from TARGET */
data sample(drop=k n);

  retain k 300 n;
  if _n_=1 then n=total;
  set TARGET nobs=total;

  if ranuni(1230498) <= k/n then do;
     output;
     k=k-1;
     end;

  n=n-1;

  if k=0 then stop;
run;
```

Notice this creates a TARGET dataset containing the records eligible for the sample.  Change the value of K to whatever sample size you want.

Answer (score 0):

The proc sql function monotonic() will give you the row number.

It is not supported/ documented so do not use in a production system